# Get rid of the standard onTouch Animation of a Button

Tags: swift, swiftui

When I implement a Button in SwiftUI this Button always has a standard animation when you click on it. A slight opacity animation. Is there a way to get rid of that animation?
Here is a simple example.

Here is a small video -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/mX9VT.jpg

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {

VStack{

  Button(action: {
    // do somethinh
  }) {
    VStack{

      ZStack{
        Circle()
          .fill(Color.white)
          .frame(width: 45, height: 45, alignment: .center)

        Image(systemName: "xmark.circle")
          .foregroundColor(Color.black)
          .font(Font.system(size: 18, weight: .thin))
          .padding(6)
      }

      Text("Press")
        .foregroundColor( Color.white)

    }.frame(width: 300, height: 300, alignment: .center)
  }
}.background(Color.green)
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own `ButtonStyle` which will override the default animation:

```
public struct ButtonWithoutAnimation: ButtonStyle {
    public func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
    }
}
```

Now just set the the style on the `Button`:

```
Button(action: { .. } {
..
}.buttonStyle(ButtonWithoutAnimation())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get what you want by creating your own `buttonStyle`. This way you have to specify an animation to use on tap. If you don't specify any animation the button won't have any animation. For example:

```
struct NoAnimationButton: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button(action: {
                // do somethinh
            }) {
                VStack{
                    ZStack{
                        Circle()
                            .fill(Color.white)
                            .frame(width: 45, height: 45, alignment: .center)
                    Image(systemName: "xmark.circle")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        .font(Font.system(size: 18, weight: .thin))
                        .padding(6)
                    }
                    Text("Press")
                        .foregroundColor( Color.white)
                }
                .frame(width: 300, height: 300, alignment: .center)
            }
        }
        .background(Color.green)
        .buttonStyle(NoAnimationButton())
    }
}
```

Consider that you can always avoid using the `Button` view and implement the `onTapGesture` on your whole tappable view (or wherever you need it):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            VStack{
                ZStack{
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color.white)
                        .frame(width: 45, height: 45, alignment: .center)
                    Image(systemName: "xmark.circle")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        .font(Font.system(size: 18, weight: .thin))
                        .padding(6)
                }
                Text("Press")
                    .foregroundColor( Color.white)
            }
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300, alignment: .center)
        }
        .background(Color.green)
        .onTapGesture {
            //manage click
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** Just to make an example of a `buttonStyle` with animation:

```
struct ScaleEffectButton: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 0.9 : 1)
    }
}
```